# Webrtc app develop, web and android

Tags: javascript, java, android, web, webrtc

I have a study project which consists in using the webrtc for a web audio video chat application and also its mobile version android ios. I have seen many different tutos, but I have to build my own server and use it locally. So you have some tutorial or technical advice? thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make an hybrid app means in cordova then try this link in this u can get all your answers 
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/

and if u want to make a native app in android and ios then you should try this links

https://tokbox.com/

https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this repo: [webrtc](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/) as well as this boilerplate: https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc - helped me a quite a lot.